# Как имя поля переименовать? в доках что то не нашел ниче

Tags: graphql

Сабж. Везде говорят на ютубе что можно, но как не говорят ((

```
const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'posts',
    description: 'This represent a posts',
    fields: () => ({
        post_id: {
            name: 'postId',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
        },
    }),
});
```

если кто не понял, речь про **post_id** приходящем из бд

надо чтобы наружу смотрел **postId**

не спрашивайте нахера мне это, просто надо

гуглил, но чет тоже не нашел нифига, вопросы есть подобные, ответа нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам спросил сам ответил

```
const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'posts',
    description: 'This represent a posts',
    fields: () => ({
        postId: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
            resolve: (row, args, ctx) => (row.postId = row.post_id), <= ответ =
        },
    }),
});
```

еще можно сократить, так как это применяется непосредственно к полю

```
resolve: (row, args, ctx) => row.post_id
```

но если полей много, то придется все перечислять, но там все равно схему описывать всю, так что не критично